# Git stash freezes (console becomes unresponsive)

Tags: git, git-stash

Git is freezing up on any kind of `git stash` command.

[image]

Press [Enter] nothing happens...ever.

But other git commands seem to work fine. I can pull, commit, etc.

[image]

I tried it from the command line multiple times. I tried it on multiple repository locations (some of which are clean checkouts.) I restarted my computer multiple times. I even uninstalled git, and reinstalled git with the same result: `stash` freezes until I kill it from TM.

As a final added complication, I'm running SourceTree (1.8). I've got SourceTree running an embedded Git version:
[image]

Guess what? If I stash using SourceTree...it works just fine.

- Windows 10, 64bit
- Git 2.8.4

Comment: Did you try with an older git? 2.8.3 or before, just to see if the issue persists?

Comment: I just tried with a Windows 10 and git 2.8.4. `git stash` does not freeze on my machine.

Comment: Very kind of you to go that length and actually install for testing. Thank you.

Comment: I did try to install 2.7.4 (64bit). This is the same version that SourceTree seems to be using successfully. *Did not work. Same issue.*

Comment: No need to install anything: unzip https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.4-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want, and add that git2.8.4/bin folder to your PATH in order to try a git stash. But make sure to do that in a CMD session, not in a git bash shell.

Comment: @VonC Nice! Will try next. Btw, you stated I should add the `\bid` folder to the path. Other places it seems to suggest the `\cmd` folder. Is there a difference? Does it matter?

Comment: You can add both actually. I meant `bin`, not `bid`: `set PATH=C:\path\to\git2.8.4\bin;C:\path\to\git2.8.4\cmd;%PATH%`. I usually *also* add `C:\path\to\git2.8.4\usr\bin`, for the 400+ linux commands.

Comment: Hey @LimaNightHawk - You might want to look at your blurring tool - it's quite easy to read your name

Answer (score 2):

I'll keep this updated as I find out more, but as for now, it looks like this is an issue with "Cylance Agent", an application my employer mandates on my development computer  :/

I noticed it was "protecting" me against bash.exe (out of the git directory).

As of now I cannot disable or remove Cylance. I'll talk to my admin and see if he can help me turn it off...then we'll see if git works.

UPDATE
Per @VonC, I tried unzipping and running. It still froze. I restarted my machine (to be sure), and moved the directory from where I had it before (thinking that Cylance might have cached the location, but it still froze.

I noticed that SourceTree's version (which works) is a 32 bit version, so I tried downloading the zip of [2.8.4 32bit](https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/23216272/8bf7f0ee-2ca1-11e6-81d9-7171ddd60da7.exe?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ%2F20160611%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160611T211928Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=ab246ee4c148275be1aa588da45d3864bb129b527e5acf9e9fda5231a1126bd5&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DPortableGit-2.8.4-32-bit.7z.exe&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream)...and it works like a champ! So, **Look's like whatever the issue is, it's a 64bit Git isssue**.

Will continue with updates.

Comment: Well spotted on the 32bits issue. I didn't know there were 32bits Windows still running out there ;)

Comment: To be clear, I *am* running a 64bit OS. But for some reason the 64bit version of Git won't stash, but the 32bit version of Git will. (Updated question and answer to make this more clear.) Again, I think it's all somehow related to Cylance.

Comment: OK. I wasn't aware of the cylance anti-virus (https://www.cylance.com/). Maybe there is an exclusion rule to configure?

Comment: I got a malwarebytes update this morning, and now this is happening.  You experience has provided me with a good clue; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate (hack), in light of my other answer, I've decided to piggyback on the SourceTree's local "Embedded" version of Git that does work.

- I uninstalled my 2.8.4 version.
- I manually added the SourceTree git path to my Windows Environment path. for me this was `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\cmd`

Works like a champ! Good temp fix until I can sort out the Cylance issue.